# How did Davros survive the events of 'Genesis of the Daleks'?

Tags: doctor-who

In the BBC-made serialization *[Genesis of the Daleks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_of_the_Daleks)* (1975) the Daleks declare that Davros is inferior to them and that he must be exterminated.

He is then apparently killed off screen, but in later seasons he is shown to be alive.

How did he survive being shot by the Daleks? Was the event simply retconned away?

Answer (score 3):

This was addressed in *[Destiny of the Daleks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_of_the_Daleks)* (1979). They killed him, but he refused to stay dead.

> **DOCTOR:** *No, no, no, we had that conversation last time we met. I'm more interested in your survival. I saw you destroyed. The Daleks blasted you at point-blank range.*
>
> **DAVROS:** *Ha! There was damage to my primary life support system. The secondary and back-up circuits switched in immediately. Synthetic tissue regeneration took place whilst bodily organs were held in long-term suspension.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Blimey, wasn't that outstaying your welcome in rather a big way?*